# Google Chrome wakes hard drives

Tags: google-chrome

Each time you start Google Chrome, all disks are awakened. Firefox does not. Why Google Chrome makes it and how to disable it?

- PC
- Windows 7 Ultimate
- Google Chrome (newest)

Comment: I think that's googles internal stuff .. :) you can't edit applications working process :) ..